# Sollte "New [card]" dekliniert werden?

Tags: english-to-german, declension

Wenn möchte man *new* für ein Programm übersetzen, sollte man es deklinieren? In diesem Fall ist es auf eine Karte bezogen. Sollte es mit *Neue* oder *Neu* übersetzt werden?

Ich denke, dass könnten *Neue* sein, weil *Karte* feminin ist. Aber *Neu*, ob es ist mit Nomen benutzt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be either "Neue Karte" or "Neu" but not "Neue".

It's different in other languages by the way. Say, in Russian, you would specify the gender even if the noun is missing. But in German, if the label of a button in some software is shortened to just one word, the adverb is used, which carries no gender ending.

Comment: You're still new here, so you probably wouldn't know this, but the custom is to write answers in the same language as the question, assuming you're fluent enough to do so. Just for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I figured, it is easier for OP to read an answer in English, as German seems to be not his native tongue.

Comment: I think the reasoning is that people may know German better than English, even if their first language isn't German.

Comment: Good point! Will stick to the rule next time!